# Exclude fields serializing using Groovy JsonOutput

Tags: json, serialization, groovy

How to exclude specific fields from being serialized when using the `JsonOutput.toJson(..)` in groovy?

Given class:

```
class Dummy {
  String f1
  transient String f2
}
```

Code:

```
// synthetic getter and setter should be preserved
Dummy dummy = new Dummy(f1: "hello", f2: "world")
String json = JsonOutput. toJson(dummy )
println json
```

Will result in:

```
{"f1":"hello", "f2":"world"}
```

Should result in:

```
{"f1":"hello"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make the f2 property explicitly private

```
class Dummy {   

String f1   
private String f2

}
```

Update:
I don't believe there is a "clear" way of doing this - correct me if I'm wrong. The only solution I can think of is defining a getter method with an unusual naming, ex:

```
class Dummy {     
String f1    
private String f2
def f2Value() { return f2 }
}
```

This way the field value would be accessible, but will be ignored by JsonOutput.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case it is not longer possible to access the field. Maybe I oversimplified my question for this, I will update it.

Comment: can't think of a clear way of doing it - updated my answer with maybe a possible solution - depending what your project needs

Comment: Seems to be the way with JsonOutput, otherwise back to Jackson.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using groovy >= [2.5.0](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/json/JsonGenerator.html) you could use `JsonGenerator.Options` to exclude fields:

```
class Dummy {
    String f1
    String f2
}
def dummy = new Dummy(f1: "hello", f2: "world")
def generator = new groovy.json.JsonGenerator.Options()
    .excludeFieldsByName('f2')
    .build()
assert generator.toJson(dummy)=='{"f1":"hello"}'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

All properties as per the definition of Groovy are taken.
You could e. g. make the getter inoperable like

```
class Dummy {
  String f1
  String f2
  def getF2() {
    throw new RuntimeException()
  }
}

groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(new Dummy(f1: "hello", f2: "world"))
```

which will return `{"f1":"hello"}`

Comment: Probably, but do you know an alternative?

Comment: btw also in this case you won't be able to get f2 value at all from outside

Comment: You can just define a different getter without beansyntax.